# How to create CSS Line

Tags: css, graphics, line

How to make HTML file like below line image style? Please help. I want to use CSS.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right click the page and view source, it's really just down to sifting through whats in the source, but it you're a beginner i would start out on simpler projects since this one looks like it uses heavy CSS, but if you know basic CSS then the answer is in the page's

I would recommend working on something a bit easier before trying something like this, get  used to working with CSS selectors and things like :hover

Comment: This is psd file not html file. I have need to PSD to Html. Please advice me how to make it HTML file.